# HTTP Request headers

Tags: ios, objective-c, http-headers, httprequest

Okay. I've been working with raw HTTP Request and found out that I can post the Raw HTTP Response into NSLog and i've nearly cracked the raw HTTP Request into NSLog. I'm just abit stuck now.

**Code Example**

```
   NSString *CurrentWebURL = webView.request.URL.absoluteString;
   NSURLSession *session= [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
   [[session dataTaskWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:CurrentWebURL]] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
   NSDictionary *requestdictionary = [request allHTTPHeaderFields];
   NSLog(@"----shouldStartLoadWithRequest Raw HTTPRequest Start ----");
   for (NSString *Object in [requestdictionary allKeys]) {
         NSLog(@"%@: %@",Object, [requestdictionary objectForKey:Object]);
   }
   NSLog(@"----shouldStartLoadWithRequest Raw HTTPRequest Finish ----"] withlevel:SPECIAL_LOG);

   }]resume];
```

**Raw Request:**

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_0_6 like Mac OS X)  AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/11B651
```

It should be showing me "Get:URL", "HOST", "Connection: Keep-alive", "Accept-Encoding", "Accept", "Cookie", "Connection", "Accept-Language" and "User-Agent".

My question is why is it only showing the "Accept" and "User-Agent"?

**Making Request:**

```
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:PortalURL];

  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
  [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:YES];
  [request setHTTPMethod: @"GET"];
```

**Fiddler Request Trace (Without any custom headers):**

```
  GET http://URL/ HTTP/1.1
  Host: Host.co.uk
  Connection: keep-alive
  Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
  Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
  Cookie: IsosecCookie=Chris%20Beckett
  Connection: keep-alive
  Accept-Language: en-gb
  User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_0_6 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/11B651
```

**Logging Request Headers in NSLog:**

```
  Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
  User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_0_6 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/11B651
```

Comment: Can you show how you're creating your `request` object and setting your header fields?

Comment: @Stonz2 Added the request object for you and i don't want to set any custom header fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come to the conclusion that it's not possible to get the raw HTTP request in iOS with NSURLRequest, you're only able to get "Accept" and "User-Agent".

However i've done a work around, to get the raw HTTP request i've used php to get the headers. I know it's not the best solution but it works and it's great being able to log this information without having to keep going through a proxy like Fiddler or Charles proxy.

**iOS code**

```
NSURL *PHPURL = ([NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://office.isosec.co.uk/Audit/testRequest.php?"]]);
request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:PHPURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:10.0];
[request setHTTPMethod: @"GET"];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:YES];

NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];

PHPResponse = [NSMutableData data];

if( connection == nil ) {
    [ViewController remoteLog:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"PHPRequest Connection Failed"] withlevel:SPECIAL_LOG];
} else {
    [ViewController remoteLog:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"PHPRequest Connection Started"] withlevel:SPECIAL_LOG];
    [connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop]
forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [connection start];
}
```

**PHP code**

```
foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) {
    echo "$name: $value,";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get the URL Request headers that actually did get sent to the server by requesting the task's `currentRequest`, which will give you more than just `Accept` and `User-Agent`, at least in my limited testing:

```
__block NSURLSessionDataTask *task = nil; // Use __block because we need to reference this particular pointer, not its current address

task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:originalRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSURLRequest *request = task.currentRequest;

    NSLog(@"Request HTTP Headers: %@", request.allHTTPHeaderFields);
}];

[task resume];
```

Edit: Unfortunately, it seems that it doesn't give you all the headers, just a few more like `Accept-Encoding` and `Accept-Language`.