# Difference in headers of two servers crashes the application

Tags: php, web-services, api, http-headers, backend

There is one IOS application in which backend is in PHP. I have two servers and same code on both the servers.

Running APIs from hostgator server crashes the application on the other hand all APIs running fine in another server.

At IOS side the headers are different for both the server

For Hostgator headers are :

```
'Content-type → .text/json; charset=utf-8'
Connection → keep-alive
Content-Type → application/json
Date → Mon, 07 Mar 2016 13:48:35 GMT
Server → nginx/1.8.1
Transfer-Encoding → chunked
```

And for another server headers are :

```
'Content-type → .text/json; charset=utf-8'
Access-Control-Allow-Origin → *
Connection → Keep-Alive
Content-Length → 634
Content-Type → application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date → Mon, 07 Mar 2016 13:42:49 GMT
Keep-Alive → timeout=5, max=100
Server → Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu)
```

I don't know what is the problem with this. Is it header's problem or server problem?

Plese Help.

Comment: The heads come from the way the server is configured. Does both the servers actually output the correct output?

Comment: yes response is same in both the server..

Answer (score 0):

Basic headers are

```
Host: www.example.com
User-Agent: LowLevelHttpRequest/1 CFNetwork/596.6 Darwin/12.5.0 (x86_64) (MacBookPro6%2C1)
Accept: "*/*"
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate    
Connection: keep-alive
```

Check [*Chris Beckett's answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24452795/4198099).

You should also try below way as decribed by [*govi's answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5696344/4198099)

```
- (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)redirectResponse
```

Also check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695914/nsurlrequest-where-an-app-can-find-the-default-headers-for-http-request) which will also help you.

Refere [NSURLRequest](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/index.html) documentation also.